# Angular 6: Accessing child component after addition

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6 in my frontend application.

One usecase is such that user performs some action and it makes addition of a row(child component) in a table(parent component). I also provide 'id' to this child component using ng-attr-id.

I need to perform some more application related activities on this newly added element. So I need to get hold of this newly added element(using document.getElementById()).

But I am not sure when and where to call document.getElementById() in the parent component? Is there any lifecycle method which is surely called after addition of child component is complete.

Comment: The related application activities on the element should probably be set up on the element itself. 
document.getElementById is not an Angular-like way to develop.

Try to set your child row component as a full custom angular component with its own class to handle events from it.

Comment: I basically want to make sure that autscrolling makes the row visible even if there are too many rows to fit in. I plan to make use of element.scrollIntoView(). But I need to ensure that child element is fully incorporated in the UI.

Comment: you can use `@ViewChildren` its gives list of children for more info check this link. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren